# Making functions accessible from other classes in same project but not in another Project

Tags: c#, project, access-modifiers, project-reference

I have a project called `Category_Helper_Project`.

Within this project are two relevant classes: `Category_Interface` and `Category_File_Manager`

The purpose of this project is that it can be referenced from other projects. It handles the underlying file system automatically when creating/accessing categories.

To do that, class `Category_Interface` accesses class `Category_File_Manager`. Functions in `Category_File_Manager` are public for this reason.

If I reference `Category_Helper_Project` from another Project, is it possible to make `Category_File_Manager` inaccessible from the other project whilst keeping it accessible from `Category_Interface?  Accessing` Category_File_Manager` directly most likely causes problems in the tree structure.

Lastly I would like to know if making `Category_File_Manager` inaccessible will also make it inaccessible in unit tests, which would be quite unfortunate.

I have found some simmilar questions such as [Making a function only accessible from one other function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998449/making-a-function-only-accessible-from-one-other-function) but they didnt really answer my questions.

Comment: [internal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control class accessibility you have a keyword you add before its declaration:

```
public class Category_File_Manager
```

If you do not add the `public` it defaults to `internal` and that would result in class being accessible from project/library that declares it and not accessible from any other, that includes tests.

You can circumvent this using [InternalsVisibleTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=net-6.0) assembly level attribute for test library benefit.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleToAttribute("Category_Helper_Project_Tests")]
```

This has a bit of a code smell that your library becomes somewhat aware of the test library but this is a case of having a cake and eating it. It is a good idea to remove such access from production code so I would wrap this in compilation if so it is not added on release build.

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: InternalsVisibleToAttribute("Category_Helper_Project_Tests")]
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

as i have read your question over and over I reckon that you want to hide a class to other projects and also make it accessible from the inside of `Category_File_Manager`
this cannot be done with one access modifier you should simply make `Category_Interface` internal to hide it from outside and make another class with only needed APIs to pass out from inside of  `Category_File_Manager`
More You can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) about access modifiers